# Probability that a random matrix of the first $n^2$ numbers is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, matrices

Suppose I fill in an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with the numbers $1, 2, 3, ..., n^2$ at random (no repeats allowed, i.e. each number shows up exactly once). What is the probability that $A$ is invertible?

For $n = 3$, an example of a non-full-rank matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\ 4&5&6\\ 7&8&9\end{bmatrix},$$ while an example of a full rank matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&4\\ 3&5&6\\ 7&8&9\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Are the numbers can repeat or they are "drawn without replacement"?

Comment: @mur_tm no repeats allowed. Each number appears exactly once. I will edit my question.

Comment: Interesting question! Do you know what the probabilities are for small $n$, say $2$ or $3$?

Comment: The probability for $n=2$ is clearly $1$.

Comment: By brute force, the probability for $n=3$ is $1 - \frac{2736}{9!} = 1 - \frac{19}{2520} \approx 99.2\%$.

Comment: Experimentally, the probability for $n=4$ seems to be about $1 - \frac 1{2500}$. The probability for $n=5$ seems to be about $1 - \frac 1{125\,000}$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A221976 indicates that for $n=4$ the probability is $1 - \frac{8290316160}{16!} \approx 99.96\%$.

Comment: @Misha Good idea to check with oeis

Comment: It might be useful to note that rank is preserved by elementary row operations, e.g. switching two rows. This could allow you to reduce the problem by considering only a special subset of matrices. E.g. by switching rows and columns, we could posit WLOG that the top left entry is a 1, and the entries in the first row and column are in increasing order.

Comment: I picked $10^8$ 5-by-5 matrices uniformly at random and got 736 non-invertible - about 1 in 136000.  It's going to get hard to get any more of these numbers by brute force experimentation.